# How do I retrieve the name of a generic class of type T in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement the Service Locator pattern in TypeScript.

Here is my code:

```
 //due to only partial knowledge of TypeScript
  private static serviceMap: Map<string, any>;

  public static get<T>(): T {
    // firstly lazily register all of the necessary services if this is the
    // first time calling get.
    if(this.serviceMap == undefined){
      this.init();
    }
    let service = this.serviceMap.get(T.name) //issue
    if(service == undefined){
      throw Error("You must register the service before retrieving it.")
    }
    return service;
  }
```

The problem is on the line marked issue. As you can see I am trying to retrieve the name of the type of class that I am passing to the method. When I try and call T.name I get this error:

> TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

How can I retrieve the name of the class of type T.

I am very new to TypeScript so I apologise in advance if the answer is super simple.

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement angular's DI?

Comment: No, I am simply trying to make a lightweight ServiceLocator. I don't want to use DependencyInjection in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service Locator's `get` method has to receive something based on which can locate the instance.

If you change the signature to this: `public static get<T>(fn: Function): T {`

then `function` type has a prop called `name` and you can use it inside `get` like this:

`let service = Locator.serviceMap.get(fn.name);`

The locator getting class instances can be called with:

`const classInstance = Locator.get<ClassC>(ClassC);`

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-p1888m).